# Inconsistent caption height in algorithm environment

Tags: captions, algorithms

I noticed that the height of the caption of the `algorithm` environment does not solely depend on the font size, but on the actual caption text as well:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclid's algorithm (Ü)}
  \label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}
    \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \While{$r\not=0$}
      \State $a\gets b$
      \State $b\gets r$
      \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
    \EndWhile
    \State \textbf{return} $b$
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic} 
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

When you remove the `(Ü)` from the caption, the height/alignment changes:

[image: caption alignment]

How can I achieve a consistent height and alignment that does not depend on the actual glyphs? Something like `\protect\vphantom{Ü}` seems to fix it in this case, but surely there is some more elegant and generic approach.

Comment: Is this really an issue? Unless you're using `beamer` overlays where the jumping would be annoying I doubt somebody will use a ruler and measure the distance of those two caption rules

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Fair enough, but even if you ignore the `(Ü)` in my animated image for a second, I think the overall spacing looks far more balanced in this "extended" version. I think that's because the [mean line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_line) is centered between the two caption rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`algorithms.sty` loads `float.sty` to define the `algorithm` environment.  `caption.sty` supports customizing of captions defined with `float.sty`.  You can use the `strut` key provided by `caption.sty` for a consistent height within captions.  Code below is without `algorithms.sty` to show what happens behind the scenes:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}
\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithm}
\newfloat{algorithm}{htbp}{loa}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[ruled]{strut=on}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\captionsetup{strut=off}
\caption{Euclid's algorithm}
\begin{verbatim}
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\While{$r\not=0$}
  \State $a\gets b$
  \State $b\gets r$
  \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\EndWhile
\State \textbf{return} $b$
\EndProcedure
\end{verbatim}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Euclid's algorithm}
\begin{verbatim}
\Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}
\State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\While{$r\not=0$}
  \State $a\gets b$
  \State $b\gets r$
  \State $r\gets a\bmod b$
\EndWhile
\State \textbf{return} $b$
\EndProcedure
\end{verbatim}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

> [image]